# typescript - replace map function

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have below const and Model,

```
export const Motors  = {
 Cars: [
  {'name': 'BMW', 'selected': true},
  {'name': 'Audi', 'selected': true}
 ],
 Trucks: [
  {'name': 'F150', 'selected': true},
  {'name': 'z320', 'selected': true}
 ]
};
```

Model,

```
export interface SomeCarRelatedModel {
 abc: string;
 def: string;
}

export interface SomeTruckRelatedModel {
 xyz: string;
 uvw: string;
}
```

I am doing simple map function to check if abc property exists and contains value, if so set the selected to true else false and so on for other properties as well.

```
public motors = Motors //exported and assigned to local variable

ngOnint() {
  this.motors.Cars.map(m => {
    if(m.name === 'BMW'){
     m.selected = this.someCarRelateadModel.abc ? 
       this.someCarRelateadModel.abc.length > 0 ? true : false;
    } else if(m.name === 'Audi'){
      m.selected = this.someCarRelateadModel.def ? 
       this.someCarRelateadModel.def.length > 0 ? true : false;
    }
  });

  this.motors.Trucks.map(m => {
   if(m.name === 'F150'){
    m.selected = this.someTruckRelateadModel.xyz ? 
     this.someTruckRelateadModel.xyz.length > 0 ? true : false;
   } else if(m.name === 'z320'){
    m.selected = this.someTruckRelateadModel.uvw ? 
     this.someCarRelateadModel.uvw.length > 0 ? true : false;
   }
  });
}
```

My code inside ngOnint method involves lot of if statement. Can this modified to better and cleaner code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat!! :D

```js
ngOnint() {
  this.dealMotors();     
}

private dealMotors(){
    Object.keys(this.motors)
          .forEach(motorType => motorType.forEach(this.dealTraffic));
}

private dealTraffic(m){
  switch(m.name){
    case 'BMW':
       m.selected = this.someCarRelateadModel.abc && this.someCarRelateadModel.abc.length;
      break;
    case 'Audi':
        m.selected = this.someCarRelateadModel.def && this.someCarRelateadModel.def.length;
      break;
    case 'F150':
       m.selected = this.someTruckRelateadModel.xyz && this.someTruckRelateadModel.xyz.length;
     break;
    case 'z320':
        m.selected = this.someTruckRelateadModel.uvw && this.someCarRelateadModel.uvw.length;
  }
}
```

**OR Shorter**

```js
motorPropMap = {
    BMW:'abc',
    Audi:'def',
    F150:'xyz',
    z320:'uvw'
}
ngOnint() {
  this.dealMotors();     
}
private dealMotors(){
    Object.keys(this.motors)
          .forEach(motorType => motorType.forEach(
                motor => (motor.selected =
                    this.someCarRelateadModel[this.motorPropMap[motor.name]] &&
                    this.someCarRelateadModel[this.motorPropMap[motor.name]].length)    
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```js
ngOnint() {

  this.dealMotors()
 
}

private dealMotors(){

 this.motors.forEach((item, i , obj)=>{
     item.forEach(element=>{
        this.dealTraffic()
     })
 })
}

private dealTraffic(m){

  switch(m.name){
    case 'BMW':
       m.selected = this.someCarRelateadModel.abc ? 
       this.someCarRelateadModel.abc.length > 0 ? true : false;
      break;
    case 'Audi':
        m.selected = this.someCarRelateadModel.def ? 
       this.someCarRelateadModel.def.length > 0 ? true : false;
      break;
    case 'F150':
       m.selected = this.someTruckRelateadModel.xyz ? 
     this.someTruckRelateadModel.xyz.length > 0 ? true : false;
     break;
    case 'z320':
        m.selected = this.someTruckRelateadModel.uvw ? 
     this.someCarRelateadModel.uvw.length > 0 ? true : false;
  }


}
```